# Пауза в jscript

Tags: jscript

Хочу спросить, есть ли в jscript нечто, подобное pause из батников, чтоб вот файл .js работал, работал, потом бац, замер, потом юзер что-то сделал и этот файл продолжил бы свою работу?

Comment: Чего конкретно вы пытаетесь добиться тем, чтобы "скрипт **бац, замер**"?

Comment: Уточните, речь идет о JavaScript вообще или о конкретно JScript?

Comment: JScript.  ............

Answer (score 0):

```
require('process');
...
process.stdout.write("Press enter to continue...");
...
```

Comment: Так это 5 секунд или что? Если через время, то не то.

Comment: Чего-то не хватает: https://postimg.cc/3ks7SYSV

Comment: https://postimg.cc/KkLd1Tm8 . Дайте, пожалуйста, пример небольшого кода, хоть с калькулятором, что ли, только, чтобы полностью.

Comment: Я написал как сделать на js , а на jscript хз...